# How to hide functions and variables in the treeview generated by doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am generating docs using doxygen and I don't want to show all the functions in the treeview. Ideally I just want to show list of Classes nested by folders that they are contained in. I looked through the documentation, but could not figure out how to hide the functions and variables. Please help!

You can see example here:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of oxygen are you using? Interesting question. Through settings this is not possible but I would expect that it might be possible through the layout file (DoxygenLayout.xml) either through setting `classmembers` or `functions` to `visible="no"`, but I don't see this happening. Probably worth an (enhancement) issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new/choose

Comment: I use 1.8.20 (latest through brew). I am actually surprised that no one wanted the same :)

Comment: I decided to go with Natural Docs instead of doxygen. Does exactly what i want right out of the box.